# Atomic store. Structures

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly, x86

I've compiled and analyzed the assembly output for:

```
struct S{
public:
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    std::atomic<S> as;
    as.store(s);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to see how does is it implemented `atomic store` in fact. It is easy when it comes to aligned "small" operands. But, now we have a wider operand so it is a more complicated situation.

In my other question ( [Atomicity on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447226/atomicity-on-x86))  @Peter Cordes said:

> For wider operands, like atomically writing new data into multiple
>   entries of a struct, you need to protect it with a lock which all
>   accesses to it respect. (You may be able to use x86 lock cmpxchg16b
>   with a retry loop to do an atomic 16b store. Note that there's no way
>   to emulate it without a lock.)

Ok, but what does it mean exactly? What does it mean to lock? 
Especially, I know that `lock` is a prefix that ensures about atomicity of "prefixed" instruction. Especially, @Peter Cordes said:

> You may be able to use x86 lock cmpxchg16b
>   with a retry loop to do an atomic 16b store

I cannot understand how it is possible to keep it atomic? Ok, I can imagine that 16B chunk of memory can be stored in atomic way? But what about next iterations?

I hope that my doubts are understandable because I had a problem to express it.

---

I was debugging above program and, on my eye, the magic is behind `atomic_store`. 
I suppose that this function executes what @Peter Cordes said. If someone wants, I can paste here disassembled `__atomic_store`

Comment: You said that you have analyzed the generated machine code. Well, then *you* can tell *us* how this is implemented!

Comment: Yes, go ahead and paste in the disassembly for __atomic_store.  gcc just generates a call to it with the data to be stored passed by reference.

Comment: Am I missing the question here??

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: No, you're not missing anything, there isn't really a question here.  My "answer" started out as a comment, but then I realized it did actually answer some of what the question was asking, so I went ahead and made it an answer.  The whole thing should probably have been a comment/reply on my answer to the previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You may be able to use x86 lock cmpxchg16b with a retry loop to do an atomic 16B store

Did I really say 16b instead of 16B?  oops.  I'll fix that as part of a larger edit.

That lets you do *one* 16B atomic store, but do it as a read-modify-rewrite that keeps retrying until the compare part succeeds.  You can't use this to store more than 16B atomically.

---

> What does it mean to lock? Especially, I know that lock is a prefix that ensures about atomicity of "prefixed" instruction.

Lock as in spinlock / mutex, not `lock` prefix.  The `lock` prefix only ever works on read-modify-write instructions; there is no `lock mov [mem], eax` to do an atomic unaligned store or something.  `lock`ed bus cycles are always read-modify-write, as documented by Intel in the docs for [`cmpxchg`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html).  So a `lock mov` store would also generate a load, which has different semantics if you use it on memory-mapped I/O.  (A read can trigger side effects).

---

> I've compiled and analyzed the assembly output for ...

Why would you put that code in `main()`, and store uninitialized garbage from `s` into `as`?  Besides that, `main` is special in a few ways.  Always better to just write a function that takes an arg (or just affects a global).  And the `atomic<s>` needs to be global, not a local that can potentially be partly optimized away, if you want to be sure you're seeing what gcc "really" does.

```
#include <atomic>
struct S{ int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k;  };  // or int a[11]
std::atomic<S> as;
void atomic_struct_store_zero() {
    S s = { 0 };     // initializes all members to zero
    as.store(s);
}
```

This [compiles to](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall++-O3+-fno-verbose-asm',source:'%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Astruct+S%7B%0A++++//+int+arr%5B11%5D%3B%0A++++int+a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astd::atomic%3CS%3E+as%3B%0A%0Aint+sizeof_S+%3D+sizeof(S)%3B%0Aint+sizeof_as+%3D+sizeof(as)%3B++//+no+extra+size,+I+guess+it+doesn!'t+use+per-struct+locks%3F%0A%0Avoid+atomic_struct_store_zero()+%7B%0A++++S+s+%3D+%7B+0+%7D%3B+++++//+initializes+all+members+to+zero%0A++//+without+an+initializer+for+s:+++s.a+%3D+s.b%3B++++//+warning:+uninitialized.%0A%0A++++as.store(s)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+copies+to+a+buffer+on+the+stack+whether+the+arg+is+by+value+or+by+ref+:(%0Avoid+atomic_struct_store(const+S+%26s)+%7B%0A++as.store(s)%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) a function call to `__atomic_store`, passing src and dest pointers and a size.  Presumably it uses a lock somewhere, but the lock isn't part of `as`.  (`sizeof(as)` == `sizeof(S)` == `44`).