# Storing of wider operands in an atomic way. Why did lock solve the issue?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, x86

I am writing this post in reference to [Atomic store. Structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515404/atomic-store-structures?noredirect=1#comment64427690_38515404)

@Peter Cordes said:

> > What does it mean to lock? Especially, I know that lock is a prefix
> >     that ensures about atomicity of "prefixed" instruction.
>
> Lock as in
>   spinlock / mutex, not lock prefix. The lock prefix only ever works on
>   read-modify-write instructions; there is no lock mov [mem], eax to do
>   an atomic unaligned store or something.  locked bus cycles are always
>   read-modify-write, as documented by Intel in the docs for cmpxchg. So
>   a lock mov store would also generate a load, which has different
>   semantics if you use it on memory-mapped I/O. (A read can trigger side
>   effects).

Ok, so I understand it well. But, I cannot understand why it is copied (stored) atomically. It could be a spinlock instead of a mutex, but the situation is the same. A  critical section is safe, I agree. But there is no certainty about atomic execution of that.

I add an example to explain what I mean:

```
    struct S{int a, b, c, d, e;};

    std::mutex mut; // global
    S s = {0}; // global

//From what I understand atomic store could look like: 

store(const S& src){
    mut.lock();
    S* dst = this->getPointerOfRawStructure(); // pseudocode

    dst->a = src.a;
    dst->b = src.b;
    dst->c = src.c;
    dst->d = src.d;
    dst->e = src.e;
    // I know that we can copy it in a better (faster) way.
    mut.unlock();    
});
```

And now, let thread1 do:

```
std::atomic<S> as;
as.store(s);
```

Now, mutex is free, so thread1 succesfully calls store.

Let thread2 do something like;

```
S* ptr = &s; // address of global variable s declared before.
int ee = s->e;
```

And, let assume that `thread1` executed

```
    dst->a = src.a;
    dst->b = src.b;
    dst->c = src.c;
```

And now `thread2` executed:
`int ee = s->e;`
Thread2 sees old value of `s->e` though `as.store()` was started firstly and it should be executed in atomic way. ( The another thread cannot see a half-written variable, actually it sees).

So, I don't still understand how atomicity is ensured with lock (spinlocks/mutex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, locks and critical sections make no guarantees about what can be observed by rogue agents who just go around them.

If you do some operations in a critical section, however you implement it, then everyone who agrees to also use it can only make observations consistent with the idea what a critical section executes atomically, because their own use of the critical section happens either before or after anyone elses use of it, not during.

If you're just going to go poking around in things that were supposed to be protected by some mechanism *without using that mechanism*, obviously that mechanism is then in no position to stop Bad Things happening.

Locking the door doesn't help if someone decides to enter through the window.

Comment: Everything you said is true. So, the my thesis is:
At most 16B on modern CPU x86 can be stored/load/RMW operations in **atomic** way in a **pure** sense? So, it is impossible to store/load wider operands in atomic way? What I mean by atomic? When one CPU executes any instruction the other CPUs ( environment ) are able to see memory before or after that operation. And in a result, it is impossible to see half-written operand. Am I right?

Comment: @Gilgamesz yes, no new "pure atomic" operations can be created. With locks and such it's usually not called atomic in the first place, but I suppose if you abstract over it then it may be reasonable to emulate it that way in cases where it would otherwise be impossible.