# Understanding Atomicity and Memory Visibility in Multithreaded counter++ Operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I've encountered a common example in concurrency discussions involving a simple counter incremented in a multithreaded environment:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#ifdef ATOMIC
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int>
#else
int 
#endif    
counter(0);

void thread() {
    for(;;) {
#ifdef ATOMIC
        counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
#else 
        counter++;
#endif
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::jthread t1{thread};
    std::jthread t2{thread};
    while (true) {
        std::cout << counter
#ifdef ATOMIC
        .load(std::memory_order_relaxed) 
#endif 
        << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

In this code, the increment operation `counter++` might not work as expected in a multithreaded context due to issues with atomicity. The general understanding is that incrementing a counter involves multiple steps:

1. Fetch the current value of the counter.
2. Increment this value by 1.
3. Store the incremented value back.

However, when inspecting the compiled assembly code (*e.g.*, on [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps6Trhcs8)), I've noticed that `counter++` is translated to a single instruction: `add DWORD PTR counter[rip], 1`. This observation leads me to believe that the operation is atomic at the assembly level.

My question revolves around the atomicity and memory visibility aspects of this operation in a multithreaded context:

Despite being a single assembly instruction, why is `counter++` not considered atomic in a multithreaded environment?

How do memory visibility and caching affect this operation? Specifically, if the counter is not immediately available in the cache, does this lead to significant wait states or can the add instruction be interrupted and retried?

I'm trying to deepen my understanding of how such seemingly simple operations behave differently when introduced to the complexities of multithreading and memory architectures.

Comment: Have a read of [Threads_and_data_races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) _"...If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined..."_ . Note that the compiler can optimise on the understanding that there is no UB present.

Comment: Don't forget that unless you tell the compiler that something can be manipulated from multiple threads, the optimizer's allowed to take the easy way out, if it can find one, and assume no outside interference at all. For example, `for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i) counter++;` could be turned into `counter = 42;` Yeah. What he ^ said.

Comment: Also have a read of [std::memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) if you too much information and a headache.

Comment: *why is counter++ not considered atomic in a multithreaded environment?* -- Because it just isn't considered atomic.  If you were to give this code to any experienced MT programmer, they would say it isn't atomic, regardless of what the final assembly code looks like.

Comment: Note that just because the operation compiles to a single assembly instruction on the platforms you looked at doesn't mean it'll always compile to a single assembly instruction on every platform that supports C++.

Comment: Re, "...`add DWORD PTR counter[rip], 1`..." That single instruction; 1.fetches the current value of the counter, 2.increments that value by 1, and 3.stores the incremented value back. It may be only one line of assembly code, but as far as the memory hardware is concerned, it is a fetch followed by a store—two separate operations.

Comment: In the ATOMIC version the generated assembly is `lock add` instead of `add`. That's a clear sign that the plain `add` is not enough.

Comment: I started to write a very long answer (way too long) regarding how this instruction is actually executed on x86 CPUs (far from being simple) and finally found that there are multiple related questions/posts that can (together) actually answer this. For example, see [Atomicity of loads and stores on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447226) (especially the end), [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850).

Comment: Besides, one should keep in mind that instructions are translated to µops on all modern mainstream x86-64 CPUs. Thus, `add DWORD PTR counter[rip], 1` is translated to typically 4 µops (AGU+load+add+store). µops are scheduled and executed independently in an out-of-order way (though the sequence of 4 µops is executed in-order here due to the dependencies). Sequential consistency is guaranteed inside one thread, but another thread on the same core (SMT) can perform a store after the load µops. The same thing is true for threads scheduled on other cores. The `lock` prefix prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Despite being a single assembly instruction, why is counter++ not considered atomic in a multithreaded environment?

You mean, besides the fact that the compiler is not required to compile it into "a single assembly instruction"? You cannot look at the compiled code to know what that code means with regard to the meaning of the C++ code that generated it.

The job of a compiler is to look at C++ code, understand what it means, and translate it into something that a particular machine will execute to create that meaning. Even if one compiler happens to give `counter++` the equivalent of atomicity (and no, that doesn't even apply to this case), that means nothing about what the actual C++ code *means*.

A compiler is just a translator, and that translation is *lossy*. Critical information about the meaning of the code is lost when it is converted to assembly. So you cannot look at the assembly and know what the original C++ code *meant* to do.

If you want to understand availability and visibility, you're not going to understand it by looking at a single compiler's output. That will only tell you how that one compiler implements the rules of availability and visibility for a particular platform. If you want to understand the rules, you need to understand how they work in the higher level language that defines those rules.